# How to fetch audio file which downloaded in NsData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

in my project i have Url of audio...look at my code....

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController<AVAudioPlayerDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate>


{


    AVAudioPlayer *song;


   // NSMutableData *fileData;


    NSData *myData;


   }


 @property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *song;


@property(nonatomic,retain) NSData *myData;


@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize song,myData;


- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *myUrl;

    myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://p0.bcbits.com/download/track/60523f9784a2912348eff92f7b7e21e8/mp3-128/1269403107?c22209f7da1bd60ad42305bae71896761f6cd1f4d6c29bf401ef7e97b90c3d5939b57f5479b37ad4d41c48227740d7ba8b5f79b76aa8d6735b8f87c781f44fb019762a2903fe65aeafb30d90cb56b385e27cd770cc9f9d60e5ea3f130da6ad3db728ff7e24a09fab9f351120810ee91f78f1e94fcabc98aabb37d4248358f6da4a0fa7a74fe8c89da2a768&fsig=cd06c325fc41b6f8edb0409011e8839c&id=1269403107&stream=1&ts=1395489600.0"];


    myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myUrl];



}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning

{

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];


    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

in above code how can convert mydata into one array?????
or how can i download this audio and store in phone memory??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your audio data to device memory as like below

```
myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myUrl];

[myData writeToFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/audio.mp3"] atomically:YES];
```

To play an audio file that you saved in device :

Add `AudioToolbox.framework` and `AVFoundation.framework` to your project build

In .h file

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

In .m file

```
-(void)initPlayer
{
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

    UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;     

    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);

    NSError *err;

    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];

    audioSession.delegate = self;

    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];

    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/audio.mp3"]] error:nil];

}

-(void)playFile
{   

    if (player.playing)
    {
        [player pause];

        isPlaying = NO;

    }
    else
    {               
        [player play];

        isPlaying = YES;

    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: every time application is open then file will download..so how can check that file is already downloaded?

Comment: BOOL isExist = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/audio.mp3"]];

Comment: That is not the correct way to create a path in the documents directory. Instead, you should use code like the following:

Comment: NSString *documentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

Comment: NSString *filePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"audio.mp3"];

Comment: if we use NSHomeDirectory() instead of  [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]; , What will be the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154576/nshomedirectory-returns-different-path-each-time-iphone-app-is-restarted

Answer (score 1):

Your code for downloading the file has several problems. First, as you say, it will download the file every time. Second, you are using a synchronous download call. That code will lock up the app's user interface until the download completes or fails. If there is a network problem that could take up to 2 minutes. Rule of thumb: Don't EVER download synchronously.

You should take a look at the NSURLConnection method `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`. That method will let you download a file asynchronously and execute a block of code once the download is complete.

If you want to be able to play your sound quickly, it's a good idea to move the code to download the file into your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:` code in the app delegate. Put code there that checks to see if the file exists, and starts downloading it if not using `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`. Then, by the time you need to play the sound, it should be loaded. (The download might have failed or not be completed, so you do still need to check if it is available at the time you need to play it.)

Comment: No. Go look up the method in the Xcode documentation. Take a stab at writing your own code, and if you have problems, post a follow-up question. You'll learn a lot more if you figure this out yourself.